# How to get exclusive access to back end tables in Access 2007 when switching back end source

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have an Access database split between a front end and several back end databases (also all Access) and occasionally I will need to do maintenance to the VBA modules in the back end Access files to add functionality, fix errors, ect. Unfortunately, the way Access works, I have to have exclusive access to the back end tables in order to actually save any of the changes. I have devised a method to force close all open front end Access files linked to the back end, but I want to give the users an option to change to a local copy of the back end files (which are auto synced to their hard drive) instead of shutting them out completely. I already use the code to allow switching to a local copy of the database, but for some reason it does not free up the back end files for exclusive access privileges. Is there some other open link between the front end and back end other than the tables that I need to close or refresh in order to get exclusive rights to the back end or is this just a quirk of Access that I will have to deal with?

```
    BEDBFiles = Dir(DrivePath & "*.accdb") 'Get all BEDB files in local environment to update linked tables

    If BEDBFiles = "" Then GoTo SkipLocals 'No files found

    FNum = 0

    'Get all DB files
    Do While BEDBFiles <> ""
        FNum = FNum + 1
        ReDim Preserve FileArray(1 To FNum)
        FileArray(FNum) = BEDBFiles
        BEDBFiles = Dir()
    Loop

    For j = 1 To FNum
        DBug DrivePath & FileArray(j)
        Set BEDB = OpenDatabase(DrivePath & FileArray(j), , True)
        For Each BETDF In BEDB.TableDefs
            If Left(BETDF.Connect, 10) = ";DATABASE=" Then
                DBug "Old: " & BETDF.Connect
                Set BETDF = BEDB.TableDefs(BETDF.Name)
                If InStr(1, BETDF.Connect, "Common", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then 'Not in Common Tables BEDB
                    BETDF.Connect = ";DATABASE=" & DrivePath & Right(BETDF.Connect, 14) 'Captures same model DB
                Else
                    BETDF.Connect = ";DATABASE=" & DrivePath & "Common Tables.accdb"
                End If
                DBug "New: " & BETDF.Connect
                BETDF.RefreshLink
            End If
        Next BETDF
        BEDB.Close
        Set BEDB = Nothing
    Next j
```

Comment: The whole point of splitting Access into front end/back end databases is to remove all queries, forms, reports, code modules from the back end files. Back end files should be purely data. If you have sensitive functionality that you don't want to include in your users' front end databases then you can create a separate 'maintenance' front end for this and connect it to the same back end. The only reason you should ever need exclusive access to the back end is if you're making structural changes to the tables.

Comment: I didn't think of that, but it makes a lot of sense. The code that runs in the back end tables is for backing up data and automatically rolling over data and is called by automated scripts, but I'm pretty sure I should be able to place all of this code into a separate Access file with some minor modifications.